# R: Group-by lag variable generating different within-group lag values

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, data.table, lag

I have data grouped by an `id` variable with multiple, unique observations per quarter and with different group sizes per `id`:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(data.table)
    library(lubridate)

v2 <- sample(1:100, 15)
df <- data.frame(qy = c(rep('2016-01-01', 5), rep('2016-04-01', 5), rep('2016-10-01', 5)),
                 id = c(rep(c('a','a','b','b','c'), 3)),
                 value_t = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1),
                 value2_t = c(v2))
df$qy <- ymd(df$qy)
df <- df %>% arrange(id, qy)
> df
   qy          id      value_t value2_t
1  2016-01-01  a       0       49
2  2016-01-01  a       0        4
3  2016-01-01  b       1        5
4  2016-01-01  b       1       48
5  2016-01-01  c       0       32
6  2016-04-01  a       1       81
7  2016-04-01  a       1        6
8  2016-04-01  b       0       71
9  2016-04-01  b       0       47
10 2016-04-01  c       0       78
11 2016-10-01  a       0       31
12 2016-10-01  a       0       10
13 2016-10-01  b       1       37
14 2016-10-01  b       1       63
15 2016-10-01  c       1       36
```

I attempt to create two lag variables grouped by `id` with lags of t-1 and t-2, respectively:

```
setDT(df)[order(qy), paste0('value_t', 1:2) := shift(value_t, 1:2) , by = id]
```

Although I've grouped by `id`, the lags don't follow the grouping assignment - the lag variables are just rolling lags within the group:

```
> df
   qy          id      value_t value2_t value_t1 value_t2
1: 2016-01-01  a       0       49       NA       NA
2: 2016-01-01  a       0        4        0       NA
3: 2016-04-01  a       1       81        0        0
4: 2016-04-01  a       1        6        1        0
5: 2016-10-01  a       0       31        1        1
6: 2016-10-01  a       0       10        0        1
7: 2016-01-01  b       1        5       NA       NA
8: 2016-01-01  b       1       48        1       NA
9: 2016-04-01  b       0       71        1        1
10: 2016-04-01  b       0       47        0        1
11: 2016-10-01  b       1       37        0        0
12: 2016-10-01  b       1       63        1        0
13: 2016-01-01  c       0       32       NA       NA
14: 2016-04-01  c       0       78        0       NA
15: 2016-10-01  c       1       36        0        0
```

I would like the lag variables to respect the grouping despite there being multiple observations per quarter as follows:

```
> df
   qy          id      value_t value2_t value_t1 value_t2
1  2016-01-01  a       0       49       NA       NA
2  2016-01-01  a       0        4       NA       NA
3  2016-04-01  a       1       81        0       NA
4  2016-04-01  a       1        6        0       NA
5  2016-10-01  a       0       31        1        0
6  2016-10-01  a       0       10        1        0
7  2016-01-01  b       1        5       NA       NA
8  2016-01-01  b       1       48       NA       NA
9  2016-04-01  b       0       71        1       NA
10 2016-04-01  b       0       47        1       NA
11 2016-10-01  b       1       37        0        1
12 2016-10-01  b       1       63        0        1
13 2016-01-01  c       0       32       NA       NA
14 2016-04-01  c       0       78        0       NA
15 2016-10-01  c       1       36        0        0
```

Any suggestions in `data.table` or `dplyr` in particular would be greatly appreciated!

Update: Thanks all for your comments. I believe David A. is correct in that the main issue is the varied `id` group size, and I've updated the question to highlight this.

Comment: The result you posted looks correct to me. You can see it resets with `NA` when the `id` changes to `b` which is expected. The expected result you posted looks like you might want a `2` and `4` lag instead?

Comment: Just doing `by=id` won't help you as you are trying to do a rolling shift with different group sizes per each `id`. You should really rephrase your question in a way that we won't need to read your mind.

Comment: @DavidA It's just poorly arranged data. The should have a table like `unique(df)`, where the shift makes more sense. `mDT = unique(setDT(df))[, c("v1", "v2") := shift(value_t, 1:2), by=.(id)][]; df[mDT, on=.(qy, id), c("v1", "v2") := .(i.v1, i.v2)]` or something

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I've added the column `value2_t` that has unique values within (`id`, `qy`) pairings. This is why I have multiple observations per quarter-year. Apologies that the previous data was confusing - I was trying to make things more clear by excluding this column, but that was obviously not the result.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg - I've updated the question to reflect your comment. Please let me know if the question is still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a subset of data frame based on unique `qy` and `id`, create the lag columns `value_t1` and `value_t2`, and then merge back to the original data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# Create example data frame
set.seed(123)

v2 <- sample(1:100, 15)
df <- data.frame(qy = c(rep('2016-01-01', 5), rep('2016-04-01', 5), rep('2016-10-01', 5)),
                 id = c(rep(c('a','a','b','b','c'), 3)),
                 value_t = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1),
                 value2_t = c(v2))
df$qy <- ymd(df$qy)
df <- df %>% arrange(id, qy)

# Process the data
df2 <- df %>%
  distinct(id, qy, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value_t1 = lag(value_t, n = 1L),
         value_t2 = lag(value_t, n = 2L)) %>%
  select(-value_t, -value2_t) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = c("qy", "id")) 

df2
#            qy id value_t value2_t value_t1 value_t2
# 1  2016-01-01  a       0       29       NA       NA
# 2  2016-01-01  a       0       79       NA       NA
# 3  2016-04-01  a       1        5        0       NA
# 4  2016-04-01  a       1       50        0       NA
# 5  2016-10-01  a       0       87        1        0
# 6  2016-10-01  a       0       98        1        0
# 7  2016-01-01  b       1       41       NA       NA
# 8  2016-01-01  b       1       86       NA       NA
# 9  2016-04-01  b       0       83        1       NA
# 10 2016-04-01  b       0       51        1       NA
# 11 2016-10-01  b       1       60        0        1
# 12 2016-10-01  b       1       94        0        1
# 13 2016-01-01  c       0       91       NA       NA
# 14 2016-04-01  c       0       42        0       NA
# 15 2016-10-01  c       1        9        0        0
```

Comment: This doesn't match the desired output

Comment: Thanks @www for your suggestion. I've tried this fix as well, but the main issue is that there can be different observation counts per (`id`, `qy`), and I'm not sure how to account for this. There should only be one `value_t` value within each (`id`, `qy`), so I thought grouping by `id` would apply to the whole (`id`, `qy`) and this would be sufficient,

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for pointing that out. I did not fully understand what the OP means. Please see my update to see if this makes sense.

Comment: @kathystehl I have provided an update to my post. In the future, if you want to create an example data frame with random sampling, please add `set.seed` to ensure the reproducibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @www ! This worked really well, and also thanks for your note on `set.seed`. Will be sure to do so in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own `time_lag` function using `rle` (Run Length Encoding) and apply it to the columns:

```
library(dplyr)

time_lag = function(x, time_var, k = 1){

  shift_N = sum(rle(as.character(time_var))$lengths[0:k])

  return(c(rep(NA, shift_N), x[0:(length(x)-shift_N)]))
}

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value_t1 = time_lag(value_t, qy),
         value_t2 = time_lag(value_t, qy, 2),
         value_t3 = time_lag(value_t, qy, 3))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 15 x 7
# Groups:   id [3]
           qy     id value_t value2_t value_t1 value_t2 value_t3
       <date> <fctr>   <dbl>    <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 2016-01-01      a       0        7       NA       NA       NA
 2 2016-01-01      a       0       25       NA       NA       NA
 3 2016-04-01      a       1      100        0       NA       NA
 4 2016-04-01      a       1       20        0       NA       NA
 5 2016-10-01      a       0        1        1        0       NA
 6 2016-10-01      a       0       59        1        0       NA
 7 2016-01-01      b       1       76       NA       NA       NA
 8 2016-01-01      b       1       73       NA       NA       NA
 9 2016-04-01      b       0       69        1       NA       NA
10 2016-04-01      b       0       86        1       NA       NA
11 2016-10-01      b       1       85        0        1       NA
12 2016-10-01      b       1       40        0        1       NA
13 2016-01-01      c       0       49       NA       NA       NA
14 2016-04-01      c       0       82        0       NA       NA
15 2016-10-01      c       1       43        0        0       NA
```

**Notes:**

- `time_lag` assumes that `time_var` is sorted and that `k >= 0`
- `time_lag` first calculates the rle of `time_var` and add up the lengths of the first `k` unique time values. Let's call this sum `shift_N`
- It then attaches `shift_N` `NA`s at the beginning and removes `shift_N` elements at the end of the vector `x`
- `rle` requires an atomic vector as input, hence the `as.character`
- When applied to `dplyr::group_by`, custom functions respects groupings, so there is no extra work needed there